# Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-sync-framework

Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit 4.0 October 2010 CTP was built on Visual Studio 2010. Has anybody tried to run this on Visual Studio 2012? If so, what changes did you have to make to the code?

Answer (score 0):

a lot of changes, mainly around referencing the correct assembly due to the changes in .net 4.5 especially around XML and correcting the namespaces. but not much in terms of changing its behaviour

Comment: Would you be able to name the specific changes that were made?

Comment: no. just open up the project in VS 2012, compile it and you should what types of compile errors it will throw at you.

Comment: Thank you for your help JuneT. Apparently I didn't have the sync framework installed correct. Also, the windows phone development framework also needs to be installed unless that section is deleted from the project. On to the iPhone sample...